# Strip a specific part from bash command output result

Tags: php, bash

I am new to bash and working on simple script..

I uses this command in my script:

```
php -i | sed -n '/^Loaded Configuration File/s/.*=> //p'
```

The output is like this:

```
/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

I want to strip the version part and save it into a variable, without the dot.

I want to make a variable with only the php version, for example in the result above my variable should be:

```
version=$"74"
```

if php version 7.3, The version variable should be 73 .. and so on ..

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Have you searched for `bash string edit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about the command-line version and you want to have the version of it, you can run PHP code by it (`-r` switch) and directly fetch the information:

```sh
VERSION="$(php -r 'echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION, PHP_MINOR_VERSION;')"
printf '%s\n' "$VERSION" # 74\n
```

This spares you to pipe into sed (which is not a bad idea in general, but do as little as necessary and PHP knows about its version already).

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

Answer (score 1):

With php:

```
php  -r 'print preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", php_ini_loaded_file());'
```

Output:

```
74
```